Union types don't work in Angular ModelSignal<T> generic type
In Angular 18.1 I have the following code:
public unit = model('px');

And it works correctly, indeed if I inspect the type I get:
ModelSignal<string>

I want to provide a better type definition for the model, particularly I want my model to wrap the literal union type 'px' | '%'. For this reason I wrote:
public unit: ModelSignal<'px' | '%'> = model('px');

However, I receive the following compilation error:

Type 'ModelSignal<"px">' is not assignable to type 'ModelSignal<"%" |
"px">'.   The types of '[SIGNAL].transformFn' are incompatible between
these types.
Type '((value: "px") => "px") | undefined' is not assignable to type '((value: "%" | "px") => "%" | "px") | undefined'.
Type '(value: "px") => "px"' is not assignable to type '(value: "%" | "px") => "%" | "px"'.
Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
Type '"%" | "px"' is not assignable to type '"px"'.
Type '"%"' is not assignable to type '"px"'

It looks like there is some problem with the transformFn type definition. However, giving a glance to the source code, it seems pretty simple to me:
declare interface InputSignalNode<T, TransformT> extends SignalNode<T> {
    transformFn: ((value: TransformT) => T) | undefined;
    applyValueToInputSignal<T, TransformT>(node: InputSignalNode<T, TransformT>, value: T): void;
}

where T and TransformT, in this case, are the same type:
export declare interface ModelSignal<T> extends WritableSignal<T>, InputSignal<T>, OutputRef<T> {
    [SIGNAL]: InputSignalNode<T, T>;
}

So it seems like it's not able to assign T to T.
I feel like I'm missing something. What's preventing me from using union types in Angular model signals?
As a workaround I found:
public unit: ModelSignal<Unit> = model('px' as Unit);

But I would like to understand the reason why we need this

No need to specify the type, let the typing be infered why you specify the generic :
public unit = model<'px'|'%'>('px');


so is the focus on transformFn a blunder?

model was style typed as ModelSignal<"px">

I see, it actually makes sense

Since you are not explicitly specifying the type parameters for the model function it is throwing error.
Try this:
 public unit: ModelSignal<'px' | '%'> = model<'px' | '%'>('px');

